# Include remote file in PHP 5.x

Tags: include, php

I am need to include some resource (non php) in our php application
The url is:`http://customer_website.com/ApplicationPage`

It is required to use the include function like that:

```
<? include 'http://customer_website.com/ApplicationPage'; ?>
```

I've set the `allow_url_include = On` and `allow_url_fopen = On` but no way!

I think I still till php engine to enable include for files other than `.php`, correct? How to??

I am using php `5.3.5` on win machine, WAMP Server

Comment: What happens exactly? What kind of content are you expecting? You do know that this is not optimal because your app starts depending on the remote server's availability?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it that way!  You're saying it's non-PHP, so don't **ever** include a non-PHP resource!  That's a quick way to open the door to security vulnerabilities.

Instead, you could do

```
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Which is far more secure and less open to abuse..

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, I just needed to enable `short_open_tag`

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't do that and instead just write the full `<?php` and `?>` tags.

Comment: agree with @Czechnology. Do not enable `short_open_tag`. Also disable `allow_url_include` and use `file_get_contents($url)` as @ircmaxell has suggested.